# How to connect to hidden folder from QGIS 3.8 using Mac?

Tags: qgis

I recently updated my QGIS to the 3.8.0 and found that my previous links to hidden folders were no longer connecting. I'm working on MacOS Sierra (Version 10.12.6). I am just trying to connect to external hard drives which are located in the /Volumes/ folder, but are hidden. The QGIS documentation states that I need to add hidden browser paths to connect to hidden folders by going to the Preferences Options->Data Sources, but I can not seem to be able to type anything into the panel. Any suggestions?